# XML file from source system

Tags: xml

I have a general question about how to receive XML files.  We have 10 systems that are planning to send data in XML format on a daily basis.  When they send it, is it their responsibility to create and send XSD files as well?  If they agree to do it, should they send XSD files on a daily basis too with the XML file?

Answer (score 1):

it's no biggie to include the location of a public xsd in the xml header. If an XML provider chooses not to include an xsd, the developer on the client side can always infer the data type by *reading* the xml and making his or her code flexible enough to deal with the possibility of those different data types.

Answer (score 0):

No, you generally would not need to send schema files. You should already know what kind of XML you are prepared to process, so sending a schema with it would be unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, but what do you plan to do with them? What do you need the schema for?

Comment: how can I validate those files without the schema?

Comment: Why do you need to validate them? What will you do with them afterwards?

Comment: I want to validate if all the info is in proper datatypes..Need to generate HTML report using it

Comment: Can you trust the schema they provide you? If so, why not trust the document? If not, why use it? :)

Comment: Good question..I was trying to understand the norm that is generally followed in the industry.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, XSD files are schema files, meaning that they formally describe the elements that can be in a valid XML document.  They are primarily used to verify that each item of content in an XML document conforms to the description of the element in which the content is to be placed.  In other words you use XSD files to tell you if the XML files are put together properly.

The only time that you should need to receive an XSD file along with the XML files is when the schema changes (in other words, the kinds of elements and attributes the XML file can contain and still be valid has changed), in which case the old schema files wouldn't be accurate and you'd need to use the newer ones.

TL;DR: unless you're very frequently changing the *kinds* of elements and attributes you're using in your XML files, there should be no need to send the XSD files on a daily basis -- send them *only* when the schema changes.